# Parsing HTML tables with different row numbers

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse HTML tables, but the tables are not equal in rows with different row numbers, all tables under (form) I am selecting the (form) as SingleNode, but the (tbody) came the row not (td), I can't loop for all (td).

Part of the HTML code:

```html
<form name="DetailsForm" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" name="helpPageId" value="WF03">
    <input type="hidden" name="withMenu" value="1">
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr valign="center">
            <td class="blackHeadingLeft">Details</td>
          </tr>
          <tr></tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="whiteTd" height="21">&nbsp;AWB:</td>
            <td class="whiteTdNormal" nowrap="nowrap" height="21">&nbsp; 7777995585 </td>
            <td class="whiteTd" nowrap="nowrap" height="21">&nbsp;No of Shipment Details:</td>
            <td class="whiteTdNormal" nowrap="nowrap" height="21">&nbsp; 1 </td>
            <td class="whiteTdNormal" width="100%" height="21">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <table class="bordered-table" width="100%" border="0">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="grayTd" width="5%" height="21">&nbsp;Details</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="5%" height="21" align="center">&nbsp;Orig</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="8%" height="21" align="center">&nbsp;Location</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="7%" height="21">&nbsp;Dest</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="5%" height="21" align="center">&nbsp;Pcs</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="5%" height="21">&nbsp;Weight(kg)</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="11%" height="21">&nbsp;Volumetric Weight(kg)</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="9%" height="21">&nbsp;Date/Time</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="8%" height="21">&nbsp;Route/Cycle</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="8%" height="21">&nbsp;Post Code</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="6%" height="21">&nbsp;Product</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="9%" height="21">&nbsp;Amount</td>
            <td class="grayTd" width="9%" height="21">&nbsp;Duplicate</td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: `[here is] part of the HTML code` great. I find it difficult to follow your description - please show the (c#/HTML Agility Pack) source code, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way that I am able to do it:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Table: ");
            foreach (HtmlNode tbody in table.SelectNodes("tbody"))
            {
                if (tbody.ChildNodes.Any(x => x.Name == "tr"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TBody: ");
                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in tbody.SelectNodes("tr"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("TR: ");
                        if (cell.ChildNodes.Any(c => c.Name == "td"))
                        {
                            foreach (var item in cell.SelectNodes("td"))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("TD: ");
                                Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);
                            }
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This way it doesn't matter how many tr or td tags there are. One thing to note is that you have to add validation if there is a case in which there are no tr or td tags in the tbody.

I hope this helps.

---

Edited to include validation for tr and td tags. A similar logic can be used for all other tags that might be missing.